# Insert from PowerShell into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script that will grab from the passed folder all the `.wav` files and get some info and export to a `.csv` file, I would love to have help on inserting into a SQL Server table.

```
Param($FolderPath)
    $fulldate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
    $startPath = Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath $fulldate

$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($startPath)
for($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++) {
    $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
    if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}

$com.Items() |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
            Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path c:\Dell\audiolength.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
Get-Content c:\Dell\audiolength.csv -Encoding UTF8 | % { $_ -replace """","" } | Out-File "c:\Dell\audiolengthCLEAN.csv"
```

It is run like this

```
.\test.ps1 'c:\Dell\'
```

Right now it is inserting into a `.CSV`, but I want to insert it directly into SQL  Server.

This is what i have so far for SQL but is not working...

```
    Param(
        $FolderPath
    )
    $server = "localhost"
$Database = "Data"

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
    $fulldate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$startPath = Join-Path -Path $FolderPath -ChildPath $fulldate

$com = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace($startPath)
for($i = 0; $i -lt 64; $i++) {
    $name = $com.GetDetailsOf($com.Items, $i)
    if ($name -eq 'Length') { $lengthattribute = $i}
}
$com.Items() |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
            Size = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 1)
            DateCreated = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, 4)
            Length = $com.GetDetailsOf($_, $lengthattribute)
        } | Select-Object -Property Name,Size,DateCreated,Length 
$toto = 'Size'
foreach($i in $com) {
    $sql ="

INSERT INTO [dbo].[audiolength]
           ([Name]
           ,[Size]
           ,[DateCreated]
           ,[Length])
           VALUES 
           ('$lengthattribute' 
           ,'$toto' 
           ,'DateCreated' 
           ,'Length') 

    " 
    $Command.CommandText = $sql
    $Command.ExecuteReader()
}
$Connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: A google search turned up this: https://www.sqlshack.com/6-methods-write-powershell-output-sql-server-table/ I suggest you try something in that link and come back with an actual question.

Comment: Hello, i have already tried not only that link but other 20 and have no luck.

Comment: "No Luck" and "Not Working" do not mean anything. What is the actual problem? i.e. do you get an error? What is it? If no error, what happens when you debug the PS script. Does it run the lines you think it does? Just guessing but you proabably want to use `ExecuteNonQuery`, not `ExecuetReader`